# Should I build everytime I make a change in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to experiment with Apache superset, especially the front-end. One thing I am concerned about is the longer time to build. In documentation, they had specified two commands

*1. npm run dev-server = cross-env NODE_ENV=development BABEL_ENV=development node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --mode=development*

*2. npm run dev = webpack --mode=development --color --watch*

When I run the first one, it takes 3 mins to build and I guess I need to build it everytime to look at my changes. Second command builds the files, but there seems to be no server.

What is the way to make it hot reload as I make changes in the code?

Answer (score 0):

That is serving up the files via a node server.  If you are working on a react project in local, we usually boot up the react app directly and host it on a local port. Most modern build tools, including webpack and vite, all hot module reloading which will allow you to see changes in the browser without having to rebuild your code each time.

Comment: It is using FLASK at the backend and proxies that server for requests. So, how to make it do hot reload?

Comment: I also have same problem, with new changes to react docs and CRA no longer supported. The new way of creating project using next, remix, etc does not have HMR, so everytime i make changes, i have to rebuild and redeploy server. Can't find a solution to this.